# How to end the "i" command in ex

Tags: ex

While experimenting with the `ex` text editor, I executed the `:$i` command (which inserts text before the final line) and found myself unable to proceed.

I assumed that I could return to normal mode by pressing <kbd>esc</kbd>, similar to vi(m), but it didn't have any effect.

Now I'm struggling to find a way to save, exit, or perform any action other than typing more characters into the file.

How can I resolve this situation?

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find any information in the `man` page or through a web search, so I resorted to trying various key combinations until I found a solution.

It turns out that to return to command mode (or whatever it's called), you need to press <kbd>.</kbd> (period) followed by the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Answer (score 0):

To exit the insert mode in `ex`, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to interrupt the current command and return to the ex command prompt.

To exit with <kbd>.</kbd> an than press <kbd>enter</kbd>, you must always be on a new line and the first character must be the <kbd>.</kbd> (period). There should be no character before or after it.

From there, you can proceed with other actions such as saving, or performing additional edits or exiting the programm with `:q!`